# Bootstrap - Background Color on Row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a work in progress

```
www.codepen.io/anon/pen/yMmjZb
```

The issue I am having is that my 3rd row (the one with the 3 columns) has a background colour set but this is bleeding beyond the boundary I would like. I am suspecting due to a row being the full page width. I have tried applying the background to the columns individually but when the page is resized each column becomes a different height so the bottom of the fill isn't consistent.
Any solutions?

Comment: Please show your code in the question, not in a (non-working) link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked your code and here is the solution. Just bind the `col-md-4` with a `col-md-12` to occupy the padding and give your class `col-homepage` to it.

> **Here is pen to it-**

http://codepen.io/sahildhir_1/pen/BWXVoz

Comment: perfect, so simple! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `margins` from the row. Currently you have `-15px;` in margins. Make it `0` and row wont span the entire width.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<div class="col-md-12">` after the row. In bootstrap, we always wrap columns in a row. Just like you did in second row, you need to add `col-md-12` class after the `.row`

So the code will looks like -

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="container-fluid col-homepage">
        ....
```